# Java JDBC PreparedStatement not substituting ? with setString (MariaDB)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mariadb

I'm trying to get the books by specific author from database. I'm using JDBC with MariaDB. The driver I use is `mariadb-java-client-2.3.0.jar`.

I have the following in my DAO class.

```
public class BookDao implements Dao<Book>
{
    Connection con;
...
...
...
    public List<Book> getByAuthor(String author)
    {
        String query_str = "select * from BOOKS where Author = ?";
        List<Book> res = new ArrayList<Book>();
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query_str);
            stmt.setString(1, author);
            System.err.println(stmt);
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query_str);
            while(rset.next())
                res.add(bookFromRset(rset));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Error while selecting * from BOOKS by author");
            System.err.println(ex);
            // throw ex;
        }
        return res;
    }
...
...
...
}
```

I then call it in main like this:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        BookDao bookHandler = new BookDao();

        List<Book> books = bookHandler.getByAuthor("Stephen King");
        for(Book b : books)
        {
            System.out.println(b);
        }

    }
}
```

For some reason the result is the following:

```
sql : 'select * from BOOKS where Author = ?', parameters : [''Stephen King'']
Error while selecting * from BOOKS by author
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=61) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

It seems like it just doesn't substitute the ? symbol with my string.
What's more interesting is that I have method which gets the book by ID and it works:

```
    public Book get(int id)
    {
        String query_str = "select * from BOOKS where Id = ?";
        Book res = null;
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query_str);
            stmt.setInt(1, id);
            System.out.println(stmt);
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery();
            rset.next();

            res = bookFromRset(rset);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

I also have a `UserDao` class and it has the string substitution and it also works:

```
public class UserDao implements Dao<User>
{
    Connection con;

...

    public User get(String username, String password)
    {
        String query_str = "select * from USERS where Username = ? and Password = ?";
        User res = null;
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query_str);
            stmt.setString(1, username);
            stmt.setString(2, password);

            System.out.println(stmt);
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery();
            rset.next();

            res = userFromRset(rset);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
        return res;
    }

...

}
```

Here is the description of the BOOKS table:

```
MariaDB [library]> desc BOOKS;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name      | varchar(255) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| Author    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Genre     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Available | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

I don't understand why `getByAuthor` doesn't work. I have tried putting `'` symbols around ? but got another exception. I also tried direct substituting in method like `String query_str = "select * from BOOKS where Author = 'Stephen King'";` and it worked, but i want to use any String, so it's no use.

Any hints regarding that issue?

Comment: use `executeQuery();` **not** `executeQuery(query_str);`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you very much. Don't even know how could I miss such mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

`stmt.executeQuery(query_str)`

this is a method of `Statement` that executes the query in `query_str`, the given parameter. It does **not** execute the prepared statement. See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)).

Change to

`stmt.executeQuery()` - no parameter method

this is the method from `PreparedStatement`, [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()).